# sequelize eager loading through intermediate model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, eager-loading

I have 3 models:

ModelA, ModelB and ModelC

- ModelA belongsToMany ModelB (n:m)
- ModelB  belongsToMany ModelA (m:n)
- ModelB belongsTo ModelC (n:1)
- ModelC hasMany ModelB (1:n)

I need to get a ModelA with all it's ModelC (through the ModelB)

I believe is something like this, but I cannot get it to work, and when a create associations `through` sequelize creates weird foreignKeys and the Sequelize Docs on this topic are very incomplete for my taste

```
ModelA.findOne({
  where: ...,
  include: [
    {
      model: ModelC,
      through: ...
    }
  ]
});
```

**EDIT:** I changed all the entities to Model A,B,C because this is a question/problem about the Sequelize API; Not about Database/Model Design

Answer (score 0):

Your `User` model doesn't have direct relation with your `Company` model, but you can get `Company` through `Role` using nested includes:

```
User.findOne({
  where: ...,
  include: [
    {
      model: Role,
      include: [
         { 
            model: Company, 
            ...
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: yes but that would get me Company duplicates, and the're not even directly in the Role (when they should be)

Comment: This is nothing crazy, it's a fairly standard mapping and other ORMs make it easy to do this kind of querying, I'm sure Sequelize has a way but is not very clear

Comment: Your `Role` model should relate with `Company` through `belongsTo` relation. `belongsToMany` means `many-to-many` relation

Comment: Role belongsTo just ONE company. ex: Company A has a role "supervisor", Company B also has the role "supervisor", but they are different "supervisor" roles, because each company has it's own set of modules and permissions. Company A and Company B cannot share a Role

Comment: Meaning that there could be: Role "supervisor" from Company A which has X permissions, and Role "supervisor" from Company B which has Y permissions. They are not the same.

Comment: In any case, I'm not asking for a "better" or different design of the models, my question is related to the sequelize API

Comment: That's the problem, that you didn't define relations right, as you explained. `ModelB belongsToMany ModelC (n:1)` relation between this 2 models should go through `belongsTo`(n:1 - many-to-one), not `belongsToMany` that means (n:m - many-to-many)

Comment: I've changed the relations, now.. how do I query?

Comment: using nested includes

Comment: that's not the answer to my problem :p that would get me the ModelC nested in ModelB. I don't want ModelB

Comment: here is an Example in Eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through

Comment: your case is quite extraordinary)

Comment: try to set relation between A and C `modelA.belongsToMany(modelC, { as: 'modelC', through: '_therePivotTableNameBetweenAandC_', foreignKey: 'modelAId', otherKey: 'modelBId', targetKey: 'modelBId' })`

Comment: I'll try this and let you know :3 but I did something similar and Sequelize kept on adding strange keys, I'll fiddle with it a bit more